# CSS position absolute doesn't work in IE7

Tags: html, css

i have the following simple script, but it doesn't work in IE7

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="bottom_menus">any text here...</div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
#content
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 980px;
    background-color: lime;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#left
{
    width: 275px;
    float: left;
    background-color: olive;
    margin: 0px 0px -5000px 0;
    padding: 0 0 5000px 0;
    min-height: 400px;
}
#right
{
    width: 704px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0px 0px -5000px 0;
    padding: 0 0 5000px 0;
    min-height: 400px;
}
#bottom_menus
{
    background-color: orange;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

why position absolute doesn't work?
thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you setting the margin of `#left` and `#right` to `-5000px` and the padding of each to `5000px`?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? surely you need a left and a top attribute for position absolute.

Comment: @Jeff Rupert it is the way, how i can make left and right divs the same heigth, which is equal to max{heigth(left),heigth(right)}.

Comment: @HollyStyles the absolute div doesn't show in IE.

Comment: Which is probably also knocking off your bottom division. That's a horrible idea for making them the same height.

Comment: i need to have the same heigth...

Comment: I guess "because it's IE7" doesn't suffice as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

for absolute position to work, you must specify both direction: eg. `top` & `left`, or `bottom` & `right`etc...

For you footer (bottom_menus) to take all space you need to set:

```
#bottom_menus {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0; //assuming you need the footer to take the whole width
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

*ps: small remark, you dont need to set px unit when value is 0.*

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified a left, so it's defaulting to 0px; Since you have a margin of -5000px on the box, I'm guessing it is working, and the bottom_menus div is off the screen to the left. Absolute positioning would ignore the padding of its parent container. Try setting left: 5000px, assuming you need the negative margin and positive padding. What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: The margin and padding of 5000px are only applied to the bottom of the container, so theoretically it would be 4985px below the container, hidden by his overflow option.

Comment: @Tom i need to have #bottom menus in the bottom of right container, so i use -margins and absolute positioning... and one question, don't you know why all our gravatars become horses:DDD